# Assigning unique values in range to variables at random

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, random

i'm quite new to coding but i'm already in love.

I'm working on an (over)ambitious project but i need some help.

I'm trying to (in Python) assign 9 values (1-9) to 9 variables (the letters a-i), i have no clue how to do this and though research taught me how to assign them random numbers between those values, i don't manage to make them not overlap (other than sheer luck).

example of what i want randomly generated:
a = 7 , b = 8 , c = 4 , d = 6 , e = 9 , f = 1 , g = 2 , h = 3, i = 5

Comment: Don't generate a bunch of individual random numbers. *Shuffle*.

Comment: Have you looked at `random.sample`? `random.sample(range(1, 10), 9)`

Comment: Don't use a bunch of variables to hold your random values. Use a data structure such as a list. As @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ said, this will allow you to use something like `random.sample`, which looks like what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go the shuffle route, you can use `random.shuffle`. However, I recommend something even better: `random.sample`.

```
a, b, c, d, e = random.sample(range(1, 6), 5)
```

---

If you insist on `random.shuffle`, you'll need to make sure you convert `range` to a `list`, because `random.shuffle` works on lists only, and `range` is not of `list` type in python3.x (this explains your `TypeError`; this restriction does not exist with `random.sample`).

```
data = list(range(1, 6))
random.shuffle(data)
a, b, c, d, e = data
```

Comment: I would lean toward `shuffle` myself since it deals with the list in place and is marginally faster than `sample`. At some point you need pay the cost of creating the list for the variable assignment so you may as well do it as fast and memory efficient as possible (assuming the code is still clear.) I'm sure I'm missing something though. Could you elaborate on why sample is superior?

Comment: @MattHardcastle More concise; don't have to worry about list conversion - I assume you have noticed that `range` is causing problems for OP because of the difference b/w python versions. Furthermore - if you don't want to shuffle the list inplace, or create it in the first place, you don't need shuffle.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Python world! You can accomplish your random variable assignment by creating a list with 1 though 9 using `range`. Shuffle that list with `random.shuffle`. Then do your variable assignment. Here's some code to illustrate:

```
import random
one_through_five = list(range(1, 6))
# shuffle one_through_five in place
random.shuffle(one_through_five)
a, b, c, d, e = one_through_five
print(a, b, c, d, e)
```

Comment: Thanks a for this clear answer, sadly, when i copy paste this code into mine and adjust it to my preference, it doesn't work. But one of the errors seems to be happening in the 'import.random' "file" i guess it is.
https://gyazo.com/908110e841da57ddac4879e635a98abf
https://gyazo.com/84ce599a044d746472c063614f783b4a

Comment: ^ Oh and by the way i went from a-i (10 values) to a-e (5 values)

Comment: I fixed my example. I wasn't considering python3 when I wrote it and assumed range's output was a list. It is in python2, but isn't in python3. The example should work now. (I tested it in both this time.)